# Python/PySpark String Split Index on key:value pair modification

Tags: python, pyspark

The following split/index will retrieve the following the output `'accountv2'` from

```
Ancestor:{'ancestorPath': '/mnt/lake/RAW/Internal/origination/dbo/accountv2/1/Year=2023/Month=2/Day=2/Time=04-09', 'dfConfig': '{"sparkConfig":{"header":"true"}}', 'fileFormat': 'SQL'}
```

The split/index code is as follows:

```
Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7]
```

Can somene help modify the split/index so that it strips off the last two characters i.e v2.

So the output will be `account` not `accountv2`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is nothing you need to do in an automated pipeline, I'd suggest using

```py
string1 = "accountv2" 
string2 = string1[:-2]
```

Which cuts off the last two characters.

Comment: Hi geht, thanks for responding. Looks very simple. Thank you.

Comment: Hi I haven't tried the following yet, but shouldn't this work ```Ancestor['ancestorPath'].split("/")[7][:-2]```    ?